# About the hypotheses of the Nakayama Lemma

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, local-rings

I know the statement of Nakayama's Lemma

> Let $R$ be a local ring with maximal ideal $M$ and $I$ be a finite generated ideal of $I$ such that $MI=I$ then $I=(0)$

In this case I know the demonstration, my question is what happens if we remove the hypothesis that $I$ is finitely generated? the Lemma is still fulfilled and in this case how would the demonstration be? I have been trying to emulate the one of the case $I$ f.g but I have not been successful, any comment or suggestion I would be very grateful.

Comment: In its most general formulation, the Nakayama Lemma claims that given an arbitrary ring $A$ together with a *finitely generated* left $A$-module $M$, if the relation $\mathrm{Rad}(A).M+N=M$ occurs for a certain submodule $N$, then of necessity $N=M$. The proof crucially depends on the existence of *maximal* submodules of $M$ including $N$. This could be ensured under more general conditions than finite generation, for instance just by requiring that the quotient $M/N$ be semisimple (even of potentially infinite length).

Comment: see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/245434/i-mi-when-i-is-not-finitely-generated)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ring $k[x^{1/2},x^{1/4},x^{1/8},...]/(x)$ is a local ring that has a nil, idempotent maximal ideal generated by the powers $x^{1/2^n}$.  Obviously its maximal ideal isn't zero, so we have an example here of $I=M$ not finitely generated, and $M^2=M\neq \{0\}$.

Comment: @ΑΘΩ Yes, in my haste light night I mistyped nil.  Probably has something to do with 'idempotent' having 'potent' in it tool.  Thanks!

Comment: @ΑΘΩ huh, light night. "last night" I meant.  